# Should I inquire about an update 12 days after appealing rejection of a paper

Tags: publications

It is 12 days since the editor-in-chief told me our appeal against a publication rejection is "currently being processed". I have received no further information. Should I  inquire for an update?

Comment: Might it be good news if it takes longer?

Comment: I guess wait a little longer?

Comment: What does the "appeals" process entail? If it includes getting another review, I would assume the processing time will be months, not days.

Comment: wait 4 weeks until contacting them.

Answer (score 3):

You *could*, but 12 days is not an especially long time, and anything is possible:

- The editor-in-chief is waiting for a response from the associate editor who made the decision for your manuscript, and they are on holiday.
- The associate editor is waiting for a response from the reviewer, and they are on holiday.
- They are waiting for a second opinion from another editorial board member, and they are on holiday.

So I suppose it depends on what kind of update you're looking for. It's unlikely they'll have a final decision on your appeal, but they might be able to tell you what they're waiting for.

Comment: Thanks.The EIC gives a  response that allows us to resubmit  our paper.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you view the 12 days in the context of whatever the *typical* time frame is for reviews and subsequent publication in the journal to which you submitted the paper. If the journal usually takes 3 months to review, then I'd consider 12 days to be a very short time in which to be asking anything about your appeal.

Many journals give an indication of (i) their overall acceptance rate of submissions, (ii) typical review times, and (iii) the typical length of time between an acceptance for publication, and actual publication. All those things might give you more context in which to consider the elapse of 12 days.

An additional thing to consider is what kind of rejection it was. It's not something you mention in your post, but was the paper sent our for review and rejected on the basis of reviewers comments, or was it rejected by the editor on first-pass (perhaps because it was not a good fit for the journal).

I might add, that without knowing anything about the particular journal, 12 days sounds to me like an incredibly short time frame in which to expect a response. Just because you are appealing, rather than making a new submission, does not mean that your appeal will go to the top of the work-pile. And most journals have long backlogs.

Comment: Thanks.The EIC gives a response that allows us to resubmit our paper.